# OBIEE Upgrade from 11.1.1.5 to 11.1.1.7

Tags: oracle

Need assistance upgrading **OracleBIEE** 11.1.1.5 to 11.1.1.7 using **In-Place** upgrade i.e. with patch set assistance.

Would like to know the following :

- The Pre-Requisite work (like taking backup of the web catalog)
- The steps involved in Upgrading
- The Post-Requisite work

Would also appreciate other general information which one needs to know before upgrading. 
And if you can also add the steps for Out-place upgrade, that would be helpful.

Edit : Need for Linux 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Rittman Mead 's blog is always a great place to Seach for OBIEE issues ,
Check this link [here](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2013/04/upgrading-obiee-to-11-1-1-7/)

Answer (score 1):

This article that I wrote answers all of your general questions regarding preparation and steps to take for inplace/out of place upgrades to 11.1.1.7: http://www.rittmanmead.com/2013/04/upgrading-obiee-to-11-1-1-7/

If you have a specific question, please ask.